# How to add button to stackview using for loop in swift?

Tags: swift, loops, button, xib, uistackview

I have created a stackview using xib and want to add button to it programatically. I tried to create button and addArrangedSubview to stackview but the button is not shown.
My code:

```
for item in 1...5 {
   let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Button \(item)", for: .normal)
    self?.stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: What's the property of the stack view? same size for each time? Because you didn't set a frame for you buttons.

Comment: @Larme The stackview is suppose to contain as many button it needed, i tried to set frame for buttons let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 145, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)) but no button in the stackview

Comment: 2 questions, any chance your `self` become `nil`? and have you set any frame/constraint for your `stackView`. I just pasted your code to a playground and set constraints for `stackView` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation,

> Positioning and Sizing the Stack View
>
> Although a stack view allows you to layout its contents without using Auto Layout directly, you still need to use Auto Layout to position the stack view, itself. In general, this means pinning at least two, adjacent edges of the stack view to define its position.

Below, is a working example.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view = view

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    for item in 1...5 {
      let button = UIButton()
      button.setTitle("Button \(item)", for: .normal)
      button.backgroundColor = .red
      stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.backgroundColor = .yellow
  }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```